# files getting automatically deleted on my dual boot

Tags: linux, files, disk, deleted-files

I have two main partition on my laptop, C: where windows is and E: where my files are and one extra partion which I created by shrinking partition E: where my fidora linux is installed(in total 3 main partition). I am on fidora and create files on the E partition, when i boot into windows the created files are not there anymore. When I boot to fidora again, files are not there either. I am not sure what is automatically deleting files.

Comment: when dual booting, disable suspend/hibernate/fastboot (on both sides), otherwise filesystem corruption happens